# installation of Python Module pby

Tags: python, macos, module, graphics, artificial-intelligence

For a python project Im working on, Im trying to take a 401x401 pixel grid, place a blue dot at (201, 201), and a black 20x20 region at a random location whose center is at least 100 pixels from the blue dot's starting point. Then I want to define four possible directions of movement, which are up, down, left, and right. After that, Im planning to incorporate a probability-based movement algorithm that can be adjusted throughout many trials to figure out the ideal movement probabilities for a path to the black region with the least number of movements. For example, maybe the code will figure out to move to a black region centered at (300, 350). It needs to move up 60% of the time, down 40%, right 80%, and left 20% of the time. However, Im new to programming, and since I do not know how to create a graphic window to display this movement in python, I decided to watch a youtube video on python graphics link:(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8mM-oY2OD0k). However, my code would not do to the lack of the 'bpy module'. But when I decided to find the module on https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html I found no results. For reference, my operating system is Mac Os X version: 10.14.6.

Code:
import bpy

class WM_OT_myOp(bby.types.Operator):
"""Open the Add Cube Dialog box"""
bl_label = "Add Cube Dialogue Box"
bl_idname = "wm.myop"

```
text = bpy.props.StringProperty(name = "Enter Text", default = "")
number = bby.props.FloatProperty(name = "scae Z Axis", default = 1)

def execute(self, context):

    bpy.ops.mesh.primitative_cube_add()

    return {'FINISHED'}

def invoke(self, context, event):

    return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)
```

def register():
bpy.utils.register_class(WM_OT_myOp)

def unregister():
bpy.utils.unregister_class(WM_OT_myOp)

if **name** == "**main**":
register()

```
bpy.ops.wm.myop('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```